# How do I add someone else's Tileset in Mapbox Studio?

Tags: mapbox-studio

I'm trying to see the [Microsoft Building Footprints](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Microsoft_Building_Footprint_Data) in my hometown with the [Tileset Chetan has prepared](https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/Chetan_Gowda/diary/41705) but his [Tileset page](https://www.mapbox.com/studio/tilesets/chtnha.ms/) doesn't have the Map ID that my own Tilesets have and is required by Studio. When I'm in Studio, I enter the url for the tileset but that doesn't come up with anything.

Chetan says " If anyone wants to visualize the data in Mapbox Studio, you can use this tileset*." but there is no explanation of how to use his tileset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a few bullet points:

- click the link (log-in if needed); you can´t refer to the tileset without the link
- change to the `Styles` tab
- create or select an empty style and enter to customize
- click **`+ Add layer`** and select `microsoft | custom`
- use `Type | Fill-extrusion`
- if asked, click `Move to data`

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can follow [the steps in his GitHub repo](https://github.com/osmlab/ms-building-import/) to create and upload your own TileSet of the data.

Comment: Wonderful. I don't actually get how you knew to find the layer "Microsoft Custom". How was it in my active sources? How did Studio pick it up?

Comment: @jtfact0ry well...someone told me, ages ago, that´s how I knew it. I don´t use the Mapbox stack myself, and wouldn't (want to, really) know about their policies towards sharing TileSets; I bet it´s written in their HowTo's, Licences and Plans somewhere that you have to have either the link or the id of a tileset to use it. and btw., personally I like the idea of generating my own TileSet better than using the linked. so, yeah, this answer is not exactly backed up by experience...if someone else can fill in the gaps, just give them the reps ,)

Comment: I'm good with that. Just surprised me how it's there all of a sudden. I thought this was the full dataset for some reason so now I know I will have to download the data for the area I need. Thanks for your help